# Remove all packages from specific channel in Conda

Tags: anaconda, conda

When using Conda, I tend to install a lot of packages that come from a lot of different sources. It turns out that there are super incompatibilities lying around. I would like to remove all packages that do not come from the **defaults** or **conda-forge** channels. **How can I accomplish this?**

I realize one possible solution is to do a complete reinstall, but an alternative to this would be preferred.

Answer (score 0):

## Recreate Exported Environment

If you still want to have the packages installed, and at least attempt to install them from your trusted channels, one solution would be to export the env, remove the channels you don't want, then attempt to recreate using only the channels you do want.

To export the env in question,

```
conda env export -n your_env --file env.yaml
```

If you want to exclude all channel info from the start, you can include the `--ignore-channels` flag.  However, since it sounds like you only want to exclude specific channels, then instead, just edit the **env.yaml** file to remove those specific channels from the **channels** section of the YAML.

You may also need to include a `--no-builds` flag, in order for packages to be recognized across channels that have different build configurations.

After you have an environment YAML you are satisfied with, you can recreate the env with:

```
conda env create -f env.yaml
```

If you wish to force install overtop the previous one, you can use the `--force` flag. Or, take the more conservative route and provide a new name for the env (e.g., `-n your_env2`).

You may have to remove some packages from your YAML file if they are not available in the specific channels you trust. It may first be worth dropping some of the version requirements on those packages, just to see if other ones are available.